# 2008 iMac Stuck on Loading Screen

Tags: imac, hardware, graphics

My 2008 iMac gets stuck on the loading screen (Loading Bar, gets to about halfway).

Nothing in this guide worked. https://macreports.com/mac/

- I replaced my HD and issue still persists. The HD is now empty.
- Can't enter Recovery Mode.
- Can enter Single User Mode.
- Won't boot into an install of OS X Yosemite that I have on an external HD.
- OS X Install Discs and USB Install Drives get stuck on Loading Screen.
- Apple Hardware Test reported no problems.
- Can boot into Ubuntu Live Session from bootable USB. But only with "nomodeset". Graphics issue?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: No Recovery or Single User is par for the course, you have no OS drive. The rest may suggest it wasn't the original drive that failed. If you have the other disks that came with the Mac, then Apple Hardware Test should be on one of them. Try that & hold the D key from the chimes. Run the full tests & take photos of the screen to post here.

Comment: Good to know. But these issues also existed before I removed the original drive.

Comment: As I said, your issue doesn't appear to have been the drive.

Comment: The Hardware Test found nothing.

Comment: I'm stumped then, sorry :\

Comment: Define “loading screen.”  What are you seeing?  A black screen, an Apple logo, or a black screen?

Comment: What are the error messages, if any, that you get, for all the step described and tried? Have you tried creating a [usb installer](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201372) and trying to reinstall macOS with it? (Can't comment yet so posting as an answer).

Comment: No error messages. Just gets stuck on Loading Bar. I've tired using USB installers. They just get stuck on Loading Screen too.

Comment: Loading Bar. Gets to about halfway.

Comment: I can think of only 2 things - keyboard not working or corrupt EFI. Checkout - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63848/what-can-be-done-to-fix-a-2011-imac-that-will-not-boot-past-the-white-screen and also this https://9to5mac.com/2019/10/24/efi-firmware/ .

Comment: Ok...that’s significant.  Try booting in [Verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573).  Hold `Cmd-V` while booting. You may want to record it with your camera to catch where it stops if it reboots.  Post the last set of messages.  The fact that you’ve got a loading bar means it’s booting from *something.*  Do you have a CD in the drive?  Are you certain the HDD is blank?  Do you have any USB drives installed?

Comment: Booting into a Yosemite Install on an External Drive. But same thing was happening on the internal drive before I removed it.

Comment: Will look into the corrupt EFI thing as have tried multiple keyboards already.

Comment: Ok..so that we get this straight, you've got an external USB drive booting USB and an Internal drive doing the same thing, correct?  You likely have another failing/failed disk.  Can you boot into Recovery Mode?

Comment: To manually start up from Internet Recovery, press and hold either of these key combinations at startup:

    Option-Command-R or 
    Shift-Option-Command-R https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: The internal drive is empty. The external drive has a working version of Yosemite (works on second 2008 iMac).

Comment: Internet Recovery doesn't work on 2008 iMac.